# p:confirm dialog's OK ignored in Chrome 74

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsf, primefaces

This works nicely in Chrome 73 (and Internet Explorer, Firefox, ...) but after upgrading to Chrome 74 the OK button is ignored. I have to press it twice to close the confirm dialog, and the method in the backing is not called.

```
<ui:composition ... xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" ... >

....
<h:form id="form">
  <p:commandButton value="#{msg.button_delete}" action="#{myBacking.delete}" update="@form">
    <p:confirm header="#{msg.header_confirm}" message="#{msg.msg_my_delete}" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
  </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Primefaces 6.2, Websphere 8.5.5.5, IBM Java 1.7, Dynamic Web Module 3.0.

Any idea what causes this and how to solve it? If possible, I would like to get this to work without changing any settings in Chrome (since we have a lot of users). Alternatively, I would like to know which settings to update in Chrome to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It turns out that one solution is to upgrade to Primefaces 7.0. Then it works. However, that requires some effort (testing, etc) so I still would like to fix this with PrimeFaces 6.2, or at least understand what the cause is.

Comment: Look at the Chrome 74 releasenotes and see what changed (or in the issue list if it is a bug they introduced). Then also look in the browser console to see if there is relevant info and try to find what changed in the jquery versions between the one in PrimeFaces 6.2 and the one in 7 and see if you can 'backport' a fix. And it might even be that a PrimeFaces 6.2.x elite release fixes this too since they upgraded jquery during that cycle. (off-topic: Chrome (Google) starts to s*ck more and more)

Answer (score 0):

The only way forward (that I found) is to upgrade to Primefaces 7.0. Several other GUI details in the application stopped working as well (filter in datatables, Swedish characters, ...) so in the end it was a pretty easy choice to upgrade to Primefaces 7.0.
Primefaces 6.2 and Chrome 74 simply didn't get along.